# How to stop deleting X spaces when an indent is removed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to stop vscode from removing the indentation when I press "Backspace"? When 2 lines are selected with one that has an indent, it shifts the line from X spaces and the other one by one character...

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Are you configured for tab indents or spaces indents? If it's tab indents, you probably want to switch to spaces indents.

Comment: I always use 2 spaces indents.

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.